# Apple Watch Wrist Preference: Can you get it?

Tags: ios, button, apple-watch, settings

On my Apple Watch app, I would like to have a button off to the side, so the user doesn't have to block much of the screen while pressing the button. I think the best way to do this is put the button on the right-hand side of the screen for right-handed users, and the left-hand side for lefties.

Is there a way to get the wrist preference setting on the Apple Watch programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot do that, not even with watchOS 2. A solution would be to survey the user as an initial setup of your app.